# Achieve dynamic initialisation based on Class passed as parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create objects based on their class passed into a function.

First, I have an interface every generatable object should conform to:

```
interface Generatable{

    init(raw: NSDictionary)

}
```

and a function that would take the class as a parameter

```
func generateDynamicObjectFromClass(generatable: Generatable.Type){

    var someJSONData : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var myGeneratedObject : Generatable = generatable(raw: someJSONData) //custom initialiser of Generatable class

}
```

and then, call it like that:

```
generateDynamicObjectFromClass(MyGeneratableObject.Type)
```

#### MyGeneratableObject class

```
class MyGeneratableObject : NSObject, Generatable{

    init(raw: NSDictionary){
         //some initialisation
    }

}
```

However, MyGeneratableObject does not have a Type property, so the problem is to get the corresponding class of the underlying object during runtime. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define `generateDynamicObjectFromClass` as a *generic* function:

```
protocol Generatable {
    init(raw: NSDictionary)
}

func generateDynamicObjectFromClass<T where T:Generatable>(generatable:T.Type, otherParam: NSString = "") -> T {
    var someJSONData : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var myGeneratedObject = T(raw: someJSONData)
    return myGeneratedObject
}

class MyGeneratableObject : NSObject, Generatable {

    init(raw: NSDictionary){
        println("MyGeneratableObject init")
    }
}

var myObject1  = generateDynamicObjectFromClass(MyGeneratableObject.self, otherParam: "foo")
var myObject2  = generateDynamicObjectFromClass(MyGeneratableObject.self)
```

Alternatively, you can create the object as

```
var myObject = MyGeneratableObject(raw: NSDictionary())
```

without the need for a separate function.

Comment: Great answer, I tested it in Playground and it worked fine. How would I do this with multiple parameters ? Sorry, I am not really familiar generic functions... Let's say I changed the function to something like `func generateDynamicObjectFromClass<T where T:Generatable>(otherParam: NSString, generatable:T.Type) -> T` (which does not work), how would I have to write it ?

Comment: @the_critic: See updated answer. Actually `MyGeneratableObject.self` is the correct way to refer to the type (as far as I know). Don't know why the first version worked at all.

Comment: Ok, awesome, and one final thing: How do I make this parameter optional? I tried to add a question mark after T.Type in the parameters, but it won't let me pass nil. Any ideas ?

Comment: @the_critic: I have updated the answer once more. Optional parameters are documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_213.

Comment: Ok, but I mean the `generatable` parameter should be nil, not `otherParam`

Comment: @the_critic: I do not have a solution for that, and I strongly assume that it is not possible. For generic functions, the compiler has to deduce the generic type `T` from the call of that function.